# Reading Nginx HTTP Response Streams in Reverse Byte Order

Tags: http, nginx, http2, opus

Does Nginx or HTTP 1/2 offer ways serve a file in reverse byte order?  I'm interested in reading a binary HTTP Response stream in reverse byte order to seek a byte sequence from the end of files (which range from 5-500 MB).  My current solution uses iterative `Range` requests and byte scanning with the [Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API). That suffices but is not optimal.

The implementation goal is to calculate durations of Opus audio files as explained by ["How do I get the duration of a `.opus` file?"](https://wiki.xiph.org/OpusFAQ#How_do_I_get_the_duration_of_a_.opus_file.3F).  A server-side script (Python, Go, PHP) could always work as a fallback, but I'm curious if Nginx or another HTTP server can already do it out-of-the-box.  Preserving Opus' low-latency is important.  If an existing option does not, a custom Nginx module would be written that responds with HTTP headers containing the duration (and other Opus meta info).